# Is there a way to import & export audience using powershell on sharepoint 2010 farm?

Tags: powershell, audience-targeting, administration

We have two SharePoint 2010 Farms, would like to import the audience from the Farm-A and export the same to Farm-B. Is there a way to do it using powershell on sharepoint 2010 farm? share me if you already have such a PS script.

Answer (score 1):

I know Gary Lapointe did some STSADM extensions for this in SP2007. Audiences isnt changed from what i know in SP2010 so its worth a try http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2009/04/exporting-audiences-using-stsadm/

Comment: I have already seen this but it seems to be a C# code which might require VS on the server. we can not have VS on the production server and do not want to rewrite code complete on powershell too. kindly let me know if we have any build-in script that can be run on the server

Comment: Not sure i follow. You need only to install the wsp package with the extensions already compiled

Comment: The problem with Mr. Lapointe's solution in 2010 is that it targets SSP's. As we know, the SSP is dead in 2010 and has given rise to the service applications. I don't think the same extensions can be used across platforms.